# Bivariate Form Sum of Squares

Tags: polynomials, binary, sums-of-squares, homogeneous-equation, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $F \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be nonnegative and homogeneous of degree $2n$. Then it can be written as a sum of two squares.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the $x^{2n}$ coefficient is non zero we can write
$$f(x,y)=c\prod_{j=1}^n(x-\alpha_j y)(x-\overline{\alpha_j} y)$$
for some complex numbers $\alpha_j$ and $c>0$. Now, write
$$\prod_{j=1}^n(x-\alpha_j y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
where $u$ and $v$ are real polynomials,....